# To access a repository, do I need that specific version control on my computer?

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs

I'm new to version control. If there's an SVN repository that I'd like to download, do I have to have SVN installed on my computer to download it? Is it possible to download that SVN repository using my existing version control like CVS? or download a CVS repository with SVN?

Comment: If the provider also provides, say, a .zip or .tar.gz file containing a snapshot, you can download that without the need for SVN software.  But of course that's not downloading the repository itself; you'll have no way to view svn logs and so forth.  And you'll only be able to download versions that the provider has chosen to make available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download a SVN repository you need SVN, or GIT-SVN or similar. There are no connectors between SVN and CVS that I know about.

However, if you just want to browse some files you can often view the SVN repository in your internet browser. Most SVN installations exposes a read only version via the built in web interface. Just point your browser to the URL of the repository and can probably browse and download individual files.

Answer (score 2):

You must have an SVN client installed to retrieve a codebase from an SVN repository.

I'd recommend TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

You need subversion, or at least a program that understands it (and I'm pretty sure CVS doesn't), just like you can't, e.g. unzip a .zip file with bzip.